# Import from DWG creates duplicate contours that cause sketch errors

Tags: solidworks

I have an Illustrator file that I exported as DWG through Illustrator, and I'm using this as a wireframe for a sketch insert for an engraving. I imported the DWG file in, everything looked okay, but when trying to extrude, there was an error. Using Repair Sketch, I found the issue to be that there are just 2 layers of paths stacked on top of each other, and this is what caused the duplicate contours. There aren't any duplicate paths in Illustrator, and SolidWorks doesn't seem to identify these contours as "duplicate paths". This is what happens when one of the contours is deleted:

[image]

Is there any way to either bulk remove these contours or prevent them from doubling up to begin with? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:** Just as a clarification I used 0 stroke in Illustrator, but this still created the separate layer as shown.

Comment: Try removing the stroke ?

Comment: Stroke sounds a likely explanation. This isn't usual behaviour. That said, I find Inkskape often does a better job of exporting DXF, so will usually save as a PDF from illustrator, open with inkscape, and export the DXF from there.

Comment: I did remove stroke actually, the DXG that was recorded actually was using 0 stroke. That was my first inclination but it didn't work :c

Comment: And, what happens exporting a DXF from Inkskape instead of a DWG from illustrator?

Comment: I actually don't have Inkscape but I found a solution to this that was actually related to pathing

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being a small problem in Illustrator due to my usage of the Image Trace module. The end product of the module creates two separate paths that are joined as one, so although Illustrator doesn't identify it, it still results in 2 paths when exported into DWG. The workaround for this is to make sure to exclude all paths except for the ones pertaining to the image, and this seemed to work.

Thanks to @Jonathan and @joojaa for the pointing in the right direction!